# Is there a way to grid a tkinter element that is in a different class from the frame that i want to grid it on to

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a D&D simulator using tkinter as a gui, however because I want to make an array where each index corresponds to the row that the element is on, for the option Menu's I have created my own class that includes the information that they need such as the list of options and the stringVar. However when I run the program it does not grid the option menu onto the frame even though the object has been created.

Full code if you need it: **https://pastebin.com/2FxBcUb2**

main class that is run:

```py
class dndSimulator(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="Ampersand_on_Black (1).ICO")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "D&D simulator")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartGame,MainMenu):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartGame)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

My frame (the part where it calls the dropdown box class):

```py
def addCharactersection(self, firstColumn):
        teamid = (firstColumn//4)
        self.removeDelete(firstColumn)

        self.placeholders = self.moveelements(firstColumn, 1, len(self.teamUiItems[teamid])-1)
        self.placeholders = self.placeholders[0]
        self.charactersection = []

        self.charactersection.append(dropdownMenu("",lstoffiles))
        self.charactersection.append(tk.Entry(self))
        self.charactersection.append(ttk.Button(self, text = "Commit", command = lambda: self.commitValues(firstColumn)))

        self.teamUiItems[teamid].insert(self.placeholders, self.charactersection)

        self.teamUiItems[teamid][self.placeholders][0].dropdowngrid(self.placeholders+2, 0,1)
        self.teamUiItems[teamid][self.placeholders][1].grid(row = self.placeholders+2,column = 1, columnspan = 1)
        self.teamUiItems[teamid][self.placeholders][2].grid(row = self.placeholders+2, column = 2, columnspan = 1)
        #grid these
        self.addDelete(firstColumn)
        print(self.teamUiItems[teamid][self.placeholders])
```

and the dropdown menu class:

```py
class dropdownMenu(tk.Frame):
    '''
    create a dropdown menu where this class includes all the vars and stuff
    '''

    def __init__(self,default,list):
        super(dropdownMenu, self).__init__()
        self.default = default
        self.list = list

        self.menuvar = tk.StringVar()
        self.menuvar.set(default)
        self.menu = tk.OptionMenu(self,self.menuvar, *self.list)

    def dropdowngrid(self,prow,pcolumn,pcolumnspan):
        self.menu.grid(row = prow, column = pcolumn, columnspan = pcolumnspan)

    def dropdownforget(self):
        self.menu.grid_forget()

    def dropdowninfo(self):
        return {'row':self.menu.grid_info()['row'], 'column':self.menu.grid_info()['column'], 'columnspan':self.menu.grid_info()['columnspan']}
```

I expect it to grid onto the frame that is shown in the correct position however It does not appear even though the rest of the elements that stay within the frames class do appear.

Thank you if you can help because I have been trying to fix this for the past hour or so!

Comment: if you mean you want to grid the `dropdownMenu` then you can do `dropdownMenu().grid()`. Also there are better ways of making drop down menus, if you're trying something else with this.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to create a class that contains all of the things needed for an option menu from tkinter so I can put it in the array that is in the frame. What i need is to workout how to grid the option menu which is inside this new class that I have made into the main frame where the add character selection class is.

Comment: Hmm, if you mean that you don't see the option menu on the frame when the frame is visible then it could be many factors, but I'm not sure what?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** after testing code I can confirm you forget to use `.pack()` to show frame. (First I tried with `.grid()` but your frame is in window which uses `.pack()`)

You create your frame `dropdownMenu`

```
 self.charactersection.append(dropdownMenu("",lstoffiles))
```

and you use

```
 self.teamUiItems[teamid][self.placeholders][0].dropdowngrid(self.placeholders+2, 0,1)
```

which runs `.grid()` for `OptionMenu`

```
def dropdowngrid(self, ...):
    self.menu.grid(...)
```

but optionmenu `self.menu` is inside frame `self` and you forgot `self.pack()`

After I add this I can see it in window.

```
def dropdowngrid(self, ...):
    self.menu.grid(...)
    self.pack()
```

[image]